# Optional argument in phpDoc @method signature

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is there a way to mark argument in @method signature as optional in phpDoc?

Something like this:

```
/*
* @method bool alloc() alloc(int $filesize [, string &$result]) Allocates space for a file to be uploaded
*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, an optional argument is recognized by phpDocumentor by seeing what the arg's default value is in the method signature.  As such, using your example:

```
@method bool alloc() alloc(int $filesize, string &$result = '') Allocates space for ...
```